# How can I share Internet with my devices?

Tags: ipad, wifi

I have an iMac, that has Internet access via Ethernet cable (no Wi-Fi).

I know that my iMac has a Wi-Fi access point.

How can I share the iMac's Internet connection with an iPad?

Comment: You should accept the answer if it solved your problem. Only then one can see that this problem was solved when searching for it on stack exchange. ;)

Answer (score 7):

**`System Preferences -> Sharing -> Internet Sharing`**

**`Share your connection from ethernet -> to computers using: Wi-Fi`**

In Wi-Fi options you can select a **WEP password encryption** for your network.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just tried this - works like a charm.