# Share internet connection over Wi-Fi

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi, internet-sharing

I am using MacBook Pro with Snow Leopard, and my system is connected to internet via wired broadband connection.

I want to share internet connection from my MacBook Pro via Wi-Fi, so I can connect other devices to internet.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Great question!! +1

Comment: Your questions is related to [this here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34137/how-can-i-share-internet-with-my-devices/34139#34139).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This all happens inside the "Sharing" pane of "System Preferences":

1. Select "Internet Sharing" from the list
2. Select "Ethernet" from the popup menu
3. Click the checkbox next to "Wi-Fi"
4. If you wish to secure the wireless network a password, click the "Wi-Fi Options..." button
5. When you've got it all set up how you like, click the checkbox next to "Internet Sharing"
6. There is no step 6

[image: Internet Sharing]

Comment: thanks. can you let me know how to set password?

Comment: @I-M-JM Click the "Wi-Fi Options" button, change the "Security" to "128-bit WEP", and type a password into the fields

Comment: Step 6 for me was "Select the `Start` option from the confirmation dialog box.  Step 7 was "get confused and disappointed when the network I set up appears only once, briefly, in the list of available networks on my Android device."